# WinUI3 ItemTemplate + command binding

Tags: xaml, binding, winui-3

I implemented my own "DynamicGrid" which is separated from Grid. I implemented my own control "FileControl". Here is part of my page:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ListView
        Grid.Column="0"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Files}"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Width="200"
        Margin="0,10,0,10"
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:File_Model">
                <userControls:FileControl
                    File="{Binding}"
                    CanDelete="True"
                    DeleteCommand="{Binding DataContext.DeleteSelectedFileCommand, ElementName=iavpcUserControl}">
                </userControls:FileControl>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
    <userControls:DynamicGrid 
        Grid.Column="1"
        Margin="10"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
        Background="Transparent"
        x:Name="thisGridView"
        ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedFiles}">
        <userControls:DynamicGrid.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:File_Model">
                <userControls:FileControl
                    File="{Binding}"
                    CanDelete="True"
                    DeleteCommand="{Binding DataContext.DeleteSelectedFileCommand, ElementName=iavpcUserControl}">
                </userControls:FileControl>
            </DataTemplate>
        </userControls:DynamicGrid.ItemTemplate>
    </userControls:DynamicGrid>
</Grid>
```

My problem is that DeleteCommand inside ListView is bound and works properly. DeleteCommand inside DynamicGrid is not bound and it is still null. Visual Studio and its "XAML Binding Failures" does not show any problem and I have no exception during the loading page.

Here is my code that processes the template and adds the control to the Grid. I assume that loading the template can be a problem, but I can't find an answer what is wrong or what is missing.

```
foreach (var item in items.Select((value, i) => new { i, value }))
{
    var element = this.ItemTemplate?.LoadContent() as FrameworkElement;
    if (element != null)
    {
        Grid.SetColumn(element, (Int32)Math.Ceiling((Double)(item.i % columnCount)));
        Grid.SetRow(element, (Int32)Math.Ceiling((Double)(item.i / columnCount)));

        element.DataContext = item.value;

        grid.Children.Add(element);
    }
}
```

I will be very grateful for any suggestion or advice.

Comment: I see that the two ElementName's of the bindings are the same, and that you do not set a x:DataType for the DataTemplate of your Dynamic Grid's.  Can these be the problem?

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your reply. I tried adding "x:DataType" but the result is still the same. I have no idea what I should do since I don't see any errors and the value is still null.

Comment: I see now that you use ElementName=iavpcUserControl, but your user control has name x:Name="thisGridView".  Will it work if you remove the x:Name?  I cannot possibly reproduce your case.

Comment: "iavpUserControl" is name for page. The same name is working inside ListView, however it does not work inside my inherited grid. To be sure, I tried changing the name to "thisGridView" in the inherited grid, but the result is still the same. If I add "propertyChangedCallback" for "DependencyProperty DeleteCommandProperty" in case of ListView the method is called, but not in case of inherited grid. It seems to me that the system "ignores" this binding. I really have no idea why... Do not you know if there is a way to debug what is happening in the "LoadContent" method for the DataTemplate?

Comment: I already tried to enable "symbols" for debugger in visual studio, however it seems that most of the process is happening in the native code and therefore I can not actually find out anything

Comment: What's the purpose of your custom `DynamicGrid` control? Why don't you use an `ItemsControl`?

Comment: I need to divide the visible area into a grid depending on the number of files. The area must be filled with files, without scrolling. Two values are defined, the maximum number of columns (3) and the maximum number of rows (3). I also tried using ItemsRepeater, creating my own DynamicGridLayout which is inherited from VirtualizingLayout. But the problem is the same, even in the case of ItemsRepeater, DeleteCommand is null without any errors. At the same time, it must be said that "FileControl" is very simple, so I see no reason why it should be a problem.

Comment: I know that it would be best to provide a sample, but this is a larger application and cutting out only this part would mean at least a day of work, and I am doing this project for free for a medical facility.